# Can't get "update from subquery" statement to work in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, subquery, sql-update

I've looked all over, but can't figure out how to update a column in a table based on subquery data when matching on a customer ID.  Here's some syntax to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE TableName
   SET TableName.Revenue = Z.Revenue
FROM
(
   SELECT
      CustomerID,
      sum(Revenue) as Revenue
   FROM
   (
      SELECT
         CustomerID,
         Revenue
      FROM
         TableA
      WHERE
         CustomerID in TableF
      UNION ALL
         SELECT
            CustomerID,
            Revenue
         FROM
            TableB
         WHERE
            CustomerID in TableF
   )
   GROUP BY
      CustomerID
) Z
WHERE
   TableName.CustomerID = Z.CustomerID
```

In essence, I'm looking to update a table column if another ID column under the same table matches an ID from a subquery.  My goal is to avoid creating a whole new table from the subquery.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have? Are you getting an error message? Is it not updating the data properly? It's important to include this kind of detail.

Comment: This is just to help understand syntax of what I'd like to be able to do.  Anything I've already tried would be pretty confusing to post.  :-(

Comment: Ok, if my answer below doesn't work, please let me know. As I mentioned, I do more SQL Server than Oracle work, but I think the syntax should work on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks.  That's my background too and I've found Oracle is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not support a FROM clause for an UPDATE.  This will work:

```
UPDATE TableName
   SET TableName.Revenue =
(
   SELECT
      sum(Revenue) as Revenue
   FROM
   (
      SELECT
         CustomerID,
         Revenue
      FROM
         TableA
      WHERE
         CustomerID in (select CustomerID from TableF)
      UNION ALL
         SELECT
            CustomerID,
            Revenue
         FROM
            TableB
         WHERE
            CustomerID in (select CustomerID from TableF)
   )
   WHERE
      CustomerID = TableName.CustomerID
   GROUP BY
      CustomerID
);
```

Another option is to use the dml_expression_table syntax, which basically looks something like `update (select a.x, b.y from a join b on a.a = b.b) set x = y`.  But that's kinda weird and requires unique constraints to work.

Or you could use MERGE with only an UPDATE section.  It's unusual to use a MERGE for only an UPDATE, but since Oracle supports the ANSI standard it may help you use familiar syntax.

Comment: Thanks!  While I opted to create a new table instead, I'll keep this in mind for future use as this is a need I'll have in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're breaking normalization here (repeating the same data more than once in your database), which is likely to cause a LOT of problems down the road with trying to keep this column properly updated. Assuming that you understand that and still want to proceed, this should work:

```
UPDATE
    Table_Name
SET
    revenue = SUM(Z.revenue)
FROM
    Table_Name
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        SUM(revenue) AS revenue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            revenue
        FROM
            Table_A
        WHERE
            customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Table_F)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            revenue
        FROM
            Table_B
        WHERE
            customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Table_F)
    )
) Z ON
    Z.customer_id = Table_Name.customer_id
```

I think the problem may be that you don't have the main table in your FROM clause or specifically JOINed into the query. I don't do a lot of Oracle work, so I'm not positive, but that would be a problem if you ran this with MS SQL Server.

Comment: No, omitting the table being updated from the FROM clause wouldn't be a problem in SQL Server. The WHERE clause specifies the joining condition, and that would be enough. The only issue would be with the two `CustomerID in TableF` bits.

Comment: Thanks.  This was for a report and I just wanted a temporary table with combined revenue.  We use a software product that requires things be in a "simpler" form.